# Regex not working in c# wpf

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I want to check if entered name contains only alpha numeric data or _ or space.
Like a file name.

this is my function

```
  public bool IsAlphaNumeric(String strToCheck)
    {
        bool res;
        Regex objAlphaNumericPattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$");
        res=objAlphaNumericPattern.IsMatch(strToCheck);
        return res;
    }
```

but it returns false even for strings like "abc def"
i.e . it allows only spaceless strings like "abc12".. 
can you give the correct code..or what is wrong in my code

Comment: Where do you think you have allowed for spaces in your regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex objAlphaNumericPattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\s]+$");
```

this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+$
```

or you can also use

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$
```

Add \s to include space as well.

Comment: Regex objAlphaNumericPattern = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+$");
when i wrote this i got an error saying " Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: try  ^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$